# Google cloud load balancer custom http header is missing

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

While using Google Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer we hit the following bug. Couldn't find any information on it.

We have a custom http header in our request:
`X-<Company name>-abcde`. If we are working directly against the server all is good, but once we are working through the load balancer, than our custom header is missing. We didn't find any reference in the documentation that there is a need to white list our headers or something like that.

Why my custom header is not being transferred to my backend server while working through Google Cloud Load Balancer? And how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Data

After **a lot** of testing, these are the results I've come up with:

1. The Google Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer **does** transfer custom HTTP headers to the backend service.
2. However, it **changes** them to **lower-case**.

So, in your case, `X-Custom-Header` is transformed to `x-custom-header`.

### Solution

1. Simply change your code to read the lower-case version of your custom HTTP header. This is a simple fix, but one which may not be supported in the long-term by Google (there's **not** a word on this in Google's documentation so it's subject to change with no notice).
2. Petition Google to change this idiosyncratic behaviour or at the very least mention it clearly in their documentation.

### A little extra

As far as I know, the [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) which specified the `X-` prefix for custom HTTP headers and propagated the pseudo-standard of a capital letter for each word has been deprecated and replaced by [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) which recommends against the `X-` prefix in general and mentions nothing regarding the rest of the words in the custom HTTP header key name. If I were Google, I would change this behaviour to pass custom HTTP headers **as is** and let developers deal with the strings as they've set them.

Comment: HTTP header names are case-insensitive (RFC 7230), so Google’s behaviour is fine per the standard. The application is not following the standard by looking for the header in a case-sensitive way.

Comment: hm.. checked. seems. the lower case does not work anymore.

Comment: If the application depends on specific headers, it needs to make sure it does not depend on a specific expression.  If the app copies of the headers into a map/associative array of some kind, that map needs to support case-insensitive key lookup.  See my answer below for a Java example.   Just about all HTTP frameworks handle this correctly (often by forcing all keys to lower case).  So the culprit is likely in the app layer.

Answer (score 5):

The RFC ([RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2)) for HTTP/1.1 Message Syntax and Routing says that header fields have a case-insensitive field name. If you're relying on case to match the header that doesn't align with the RFC.

Way back in the day I looked through either the Tomcat of Jetty source and they worked with everything as a `.toLower()`.

Go has a [CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey](https://golang.org/src/net/textproto/reader.go?h=CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey#L600) where it'll format the headers in a common way to be sure everything is on the same page.

Python still harkens back to the RFC822 (hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/rfc822.py#l211) days, but it forces a `.lower()` on headers to standardize.

Basically though what the GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancer is doing is acceptable as far as the RFC is concerned.

Comment: Good find! However, in my opinion: HTTP headers are mostly used in HTTP environments, i.e. web servers. Most web servers  are Linux based. Linux environments are case sensitive unless you spend extra compute power to manipulate the string and check. That being the case, it seems `7230` just didn't really take off. Especially since the Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer product **adds** custom HTTP headers of its own, and maintains the "deprecated" naming convention of `X-Capital-Letter`. My point being, RFCs are not worth the `.txt` they're written on unless there's good, standard, adoption.

Comment: @SimpleAnecdote the vast majority of HTTP implementations I've seen work with header names in a case-insensitive way. An application that doesn't is the exception and should be fixed. BTW, case-insensitive != lowercase: "X-Capital-Letter" is not "deprecated", it's just the same header as "x-capital-letter".

Comment: @SimpleAnecdote The RFCs are fine.  Fyi, HTTP header names have always been case insensitive since the very beginning of the world wide web in the mid-1990s.  See [RFC 1945](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.html#section-4.2).  Which builds on [MIME RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.html#section-3.4.7).  These rules have never been changed wrt header names.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely an application bug.

As other answers have stated, HTTP header names are case **in**sensitive.  Ime, every time headers appear to be case **sensitive**, it is because there is a request wrapper somewhere in the application call stack.

Request wrappers like this are common (usually necessary) in Java servlet filters.  It's a common, newbie mistake to use case-sensitive matching (e.g. a regular Java `HashMap<String, T>()`) for the header names in the wrapper.

That's where I would start looking for your bug.

A reasonable way to create a Java `Map<String, T>` that is both case insensitive and that doesn't modify the keys is to use `new TreeMap<String, T>( String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER )`.

Comment: It is not an application bug. The LB doesn't forward headers from origin

Comment: I said most likely.  I stand by my answer as something useful to check during trouble-shooting and, if the issue is found at the application layer, a reasonable approach to fix it.