# HTTP request header names are converted to lower-case

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-webapi, google-cloud-run

I wrote a simple web service in .NET 7 that echos back HTTP headers. When run locally, the headers are echoed back in the same case in which they are sent. But when run on GCP Cloud Run, the header names are converted to lower-case. Just want to confirm that this is by design and isn't a behaviour that I can change.

Comment: btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849622/google-cloud-load-balancer-custom-http-header-is-missing

Answer (score 1):

HTTP header names must be processed as case-insensitive strings.

> An HTTP header consists of its case-insensitive name followed by a
> colon (:), then by its value.

It should not matter to your software which case is used. This is per the HTTP spec. Some Google services convert headers to lowercase but do not rely upon that convention as not all services do that.

Refer to the following reference:

[MDN: HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)